# OpenCV Inpaint not removing the watermark from the image Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I have tried the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
Inpainting sample.

Inpainting repairs damage to images by floodfilling
the damage with surrounding image areas.

Usage:
  inpaint.py [<image>]

Keys:
  SPACE - inpaint
  r     - reset the inpainting mask
  ESC   - exit
'''

# Python 2/3 compatibility
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import cv2
from common import Sketcher

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    try:
        fn = sys.argv[1]
    except:
        fn = '../data/fruits.jpg'

    print(__doc__)

    img = cv2.imread(fn)
    if img is None:
        print('Failed to load image file:', fn)
        sys.exit(1)

    img_mark = img.copy()
    mark = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
    sketch = Sketcher('img', [img_mark, mark], lambda : ((255, 255, 255), 255))

    while True:
        ch = cv2.waitKey()
        if ch == 27:
            break
        if ch == ord(' '):
            res = cv2.inpaint(img_mark, mark, 3, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
            cv2.imshow('inpaint', res)
        if ch == ord('r'):
            img_mark[:] = img
            mark[:] = 0
            sketch.show()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But the output what I got what the exact image and the watermark was available. I guess inpaint was capable of removing any watermark from the images. But it sound total failure in my case.

Here is the image that I try to remove the watermark:

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to remove watermarks from images ? Take a look on this [link](http://www.photoattorney.com/2007/07/watermarks-can-be-music-to-your-ears.html) and then think some more on whether you really should be doing this.

Comment: @Sunreef What I am trying is not to resell or do any mischievous activity with the image. I want to just get rid of the watermark and make a gallery, not for reuse but for show. Then I will keep a mechanism that will link the image to its sources. Completely giving the credit to the creator. But currently I am trying to learn how this watermark can be remove and how I can create a watermark that will be xtremely hard to remove.

Comment: This watermark looks like a simple change in brightness. find the watermark mask and reduce the pixel intensity inside it by some proportion

Comment: @MartinBeckett Is that feasible with openCV.. I am a bit doubtful.

Comment: It doesn't look like a perfect mathematical spiral so you would probably  detect it with canny+contour then manually pick a point inside to make a mask. All of which is possible with opencv

Comment: @MartinBeckett Dear, is there any demo I can visit so to get more insights over it. I am trying to have a universal watermark remover, but want to start with the one in the question.